# Get values of login from another page to construct a dynamic connection string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have LoginViewModel

```
        public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client ID")]
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

When the user logins, he enters the name of the database he will use so using the Client ID  I will construct a connection string which I will use to instantiate my dbcontext EF. How do I get the values of these Client ID from another page so I can retrieve it when I instantiate my SystemContext connection string

```
    public partial class SystemContext : DbContext
{
    public SystemContext()
        : base("name=SystemContext")
    {
    }
```

Comment: What is client id and how user will map client id to find DB? Are you using a master table for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right,

I used session but becomes null in another controller.
Should be

```
    var clientId = (string) HttpContext.Session["ClientID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you are trying to transfer data from Page A to Page B.

There are a few methods can transfer data:

- this.ViewBag["client"] = "xxx"; // only transfer within the same action, if you redirect to another action, the data will be lost;
- this.TempData["client"] = "xxx"; // i suggest this one
- this.Session["client"] = "xxx"; // session data

PS: you should set it in controller code; and u can use it in controller code or in page rendering.

Hope this could help you. :)